# Android unable to attach a gif to text message using an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make it so a user can select a gif in my app and send it through a text message. From what I have, you can click on a gif, then the app allows you to choose a messaging platform and starts a new message, but gives the error "Unable to attach. File not supported." and won't attach the gif to the text message. How should I go about fixing this?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()   {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View imageView, int     position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pick a messenger!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                File f = new File("/res/drawable/broke.gif");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
                intent.setType("image/gif");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send"));
            }
        });
    }
```

broke.gif is the gif I have been trying to send while testing my program.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, as Gabe notes, fewer apps than you might expect will support GIF.

However, you have a bigger problem:

> File f = new File("/res/drawable/broke.gif");

There is no `/res/drawable/broke.gif` on the Android device.

Presumably, you mean "the drawable in my project named `broke.gif`". Resources are files **on your development machine**. They are not files on the device. They are entries in the ZIP archive that is the APK file.

Sharing a drawable resource is at least theoretically possible, such as using [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider).

Comment: Would storing the gifs in an assets folder and accessing them through there help? Or is it a better idea to access them through my ImageAdapter.java class that I am already using to display the GridView of gifs for users to click on?

Comment: @EricJohnson: "Would storing the gifs in an assets folder and accessing them through there help?" -- they are less likely to be messed with by the framework. You would still need `StreamProvider` or the equivalent, or to make a copy of the asset out as a file somewhere on external storage. "Or is it a better idea to access them through my ImageAdapter.java class that I am already using to display the GridView of gifs for users to click on?" -- I have no idea what that means in the context of `ACTION_SEND`, sorry.